# Turning a couple of vectors into a list of vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

Suppose I have a collection of independent vectors, of the same length. For example,

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rep(NA, 10)
```

and I wish to turn them into a list whose length is that common length (10 in the given example), in which each element is a vector whose length is the number of independent vectors that were given. In my example, assuming `output` is the output object, I'd expect

```
> str(output)
List of 10
 $ : num [1:2] 1 NA
 ...

> output
[[1]]
[1]  1 NA
...
```

What's the common method of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `mapply` and `c`:

```
 mapply(c, x, y, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

[[1]]
[1]  1 NA

[[2]]
[1]  2 NA

..<cropped>..

[[10]]
[1] 10 NA
```

Comment: `Map` is sugar for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
split(cbind(x, y), seq(length(x)))
```

or even:

```
split(c(x, y), seq(length(x)))
```

or even (assuming `x` has no duplicate values as in your example):

```
split(c(x, y), x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that allows you to zip arbitrary number of equi-length vectors into a list, based on position of the element

```
merge_by_pos <- function(...){
  dotlist = list(...)
  lapply(seq_along(dotlist), function(i){
    Reduce('c', lapply(dotlist, '[[', i))
  })
}
x <- 1:10
y <- rep(NA, 10)
z <- 21:30

merge_by_pos(x, y, z)
```